# Build error - TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported

Tags: jss, nextjs

When not using graphql feature npm run build fails with following error:

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported
    at getNodeRequestOptions (C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1305:9)
    at C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1410:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at fetch (C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1407:9)
    at fetch (C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\cross-fetch\dist\node-ponyfill.js:10:20)
    at C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:123:42
    at step (C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:63:23)
    at Object.next (C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:44:53)
    at C:\Projects\TEMP\test-jss-next\node_modules\@sitecore-jss\sitecore-jss\node_modules\graphql-request\dist\index.js:38:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>) {
  type: 'TypeError'
}
```

I expect to not have this error or have option to skip qraphql

**Steps To Reproduce:**

- Run `jss create test-jss-nextjs-app nextjs`
- Run `cd test-jss-nextjs-app`
- Run `npm run build`

See this error

JSS Version: 18.0.0

Does anyone experience the same error?
Who knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

With Next.js, running a build will trigger a production build, which requires a service to communicate with first. The `build` target by default then needs a running Sitecore instance configured in the `scjssconfig.json`.

What you want instead likely is `npm run start`, which will start the disconnected/mock Sitecore service and run Next.js in development mode against that.

Comment: how might one go about running in disconnected mode on Vercel? The Express server that it spools up is incompatible with the serverless architecture of Vercel.